# Making Crons to quit running an existing script

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I am running a script which constantly works over my Database. How ever It is necessary to restart the script once an hour. Obviously I can't do that automatically. I don't want to use daemon, its too complex for me right now. Easier solution is to use cron job but biggest drawback is, it won't stop the last script. Script runs in infinite `while(true)` loop

However is that possible if I make function in a script, lets say

```
function exitScript()
{
  exit;
}
```

And then on Cron job if i do something like

```
php /home/Path/public_html/webservice/myScript.php exitScript and then
php /home/Path/public_html/webservice/myScript.php
```

What will be the format and How can I run both one by one using cron job or make another PHP who does so?

I need advice.

Comment: Exit 100% ENDS all your php scripts.
So your crontab have to start it again on each 1 hour..

Comment: can you explain with code what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little trick easy to made which you can use..

1st set you cron jobs to run on each hour.

```
* */1 ..... cronjob.php
```

2nd At start of your script define 1 constant with time:

```
define('SCRIPT_START_TIME', time());
```

3rd At your exit script set up a condition check to exit if 59 minutes are passed from this constant to current time.. :)

```
function exitScript()
{
  if((time() - SCRIPT_START_TIME) > 59*60){
     exit();
  }
}
```

4th at each while LOOP start the exit script .